# Generating a 54 megapixel image on iPhone 4/4S and iPad 2

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, memory-management, core-graphics

I'm currently working on a project that must generate a **collage** of a **9000x6000 pixels** resolution, generated from **15 photos**. The problem that I'm facing is that when I finish drawing I'm getting an empty image (those 15 images are not being drawn in the context).

This problem is only present on devices with **512MB of RAM** like iPhone 4/4S or iPad 2 and I think that this is a problem caused by the system because it cannot allocate enough memory for this app. When I run this line: `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(outputSize, opaque, 1.0f);` the app's memory usage raises by **216MB** and the total memory usage gets to **~240MB RAM**.

The thing that I cannot understand is why on Earth the images that I'm trying to draw within the `for loop` are not being rendered **always** on the `currentContext`? I emphasized the word **always**, because only once in 30 tests the images were rendered (without changing any line of code).

**Question nr. 2**: If this is a problem caused by the system because it cannot allocate enough memory, is there any other way to generate this image, like a CGContextRef backed by a file output stream, so that it won't keep the image in the memory?

**This is the code**:

```
CGSize outputSize = CGSizeMake(9000, 6000);
BOOL opaque = YES;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(outputSize, opaque, 1.0f);

CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(currentContext, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(currentContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, outputSize.width, outputSize.height));

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < strongSelf.images.count; i++)
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        AGAutoCollageImageData *imageData = (AGAutoCollageImageData *)strongSelf.layout.images[i];

        CGRect destinationRect = CGRectMake(floorf(imageData.destinationRectangle.origin.x * scaleXRatio),
                                            floorf(imageData.destinationRectangle.origin.y * scaleYRatio),
                                            floorf(imageData.destinationRectangle.size.width * scaleXRatio),
                                            floorf(imageData.destinationRectangle.size.height * scaleYRatio));

        CGRect sourceRect = imageData.sourceRectangle;

        // Draw clipped image
        CGImageRef clippedImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(((ALAsset *)strongSelf.images[i]).defaultRepresentation.fullScreenImage, sourceRect);
        CGContextDrawImage(currentContext, drawRect, clippedImageRef);
        CGImageRelease(clippedImageRef);
    }
}

// Pull the image from our context
strongSelf.result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

// Pop the context
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

P.S: The console doesn't show anything but '**memory warnings**', which are expected to see.

Comment: the raise of memory by 216MB is obvious since 54*4 (4 byte per pixel) is 216MB

Comment: I know that it's obvious :) but what I don't know is why those 15 images are not being drawn on the context. I posted those things about the memory usage only as hints.

Comment: *"I'm currently working on a project that must generate a collage of a 9000x6000 pixels resolution, generated from 15 photos."* -- just don't. there are very few applications on *desktops* where this is the best solution. hint: memory diagnosis tools categorize this allocation as an "insane request".

Comment: Ok, but unfortunately I can't tell this to my client. I tried to convince him that we should do the rendering on the server but no luck.

Comment: @arturgrigor why would there need to be a composite representation? hopefully not for a 200+ MB transfer. having separate images is preferable for the underlying virtual memory employed by Quartz. it's much better to work with separate resources. you *could* approach it by rendering to a memory mapped file using CGBitmapContext/CGImage, but expect you will hit dead ends at most turns using this design. so the problem is not how to accommodate the large memory demand, but how to render the images as though it were a composite because the resource demands are just impractically high.

Comment: *you could approach it by rendering to a memory mapped file…* -- that only suggests it could be possible to do, but there is no guarantee it will work. i suspect it would fail at times (e.g. in low memory conditions).

Comment: Memory mapping sounds good like a good option. I'll try this. Thanks!

Comment: @arturgrigor I still don't recommend this approach. If you insist on using a huge mapped file, then you probably want to reduce physical and virtual memory where possible. Really, I don't have a reason as to why it fails -- so that is my best guess. Only reference the images you need and dispose of them immediately. You could also reduce the memory demands in some cases by using mapped memory for the source images (as bitmap representations). Again, this is not a good approach for the reasons I mentioned above.

Comment: @panic Unfortunately I don't have any other option. I can spare 10-15 more MB from UIViewControllers, but that's all. Every time when I deal with images I dispose them immediately after working with them. I'm thinking now of removing all the controls from the presented view controller and show a snapshot of it instead, to spare a few more MB.

Comment: @justin please add the memory mapping as an answer to my question so that I can accept it, because I don't think there's another option to my problem.

Comment: @arturgrigor i don't advocate the solution. you may add it as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like a cool project.

**Tactic**: try also releasing `imageData` at the end of every loop (explicitly, after releasing the `clippedImageRef`)

**Strategic**:
If you do need to support such "low" RAM requirements with such "high" input, maybe you should consider 2 alternative options:

1. Compress (obviously): even minimal, naked to the eye, JPEG compression can go a long way.
2. Split: never "really" merge the image. Have an arrayed datastructure which represents a `BigImage`. make utilities for the presentation logic.